# Wordpress Multisite with Wildcard Certificates not mapping correctly

Tags: multisite, subdomains, https, domain-mapping, virtual-hosts

I have set up a Wordpress Multisite with LAMP successfully and it currently has the following structure

- a.com (wordpress primary domain)

  1. a1.a.com
- b.com

  1. b1.b.com
  2. b2.b.com
  3. b3.b.com
- c.com

I created virtual hosts configurations for the three domains mapping to the same WordPress Multisite directory, and I am running the WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugging to handle redirections and so far has been working great with http.

Then I created the certificates for https:

- cert 1 => a.com, *.a.com
- cert 2 => b.com, *.b.com
- cert 3 => c.com

And set automatic https redirecting in the virtualhost configuration for all the domains.

Current status:

- *a.com* and *a1.a.com* are working with https, but *a1.a.com* required plugins for redirection from http to https.
- *b.com* is working with https
- *b.com* subdomains are not working with https, pluggins have led to use *.a.com certificate which results in security warning for all sites.
- *c.com* is working with https.

Can someone please help me understand where can the problem be?

I'm thinking about creating a virtual host configuration for each subdomain in *b.com*, but it will be more like a patch than a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was getting wrong the virtual host configuration file to redirect all http requests to https

This is my current working configuration:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/a.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@a.com
    ServerName a.com
    ServerAlias *.a.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/a.com/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =a1.a.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =a.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/a.com-le-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@a.com
    ServerName a.com
    ServerAlias *.a.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/a.com/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

However it is required to update the virtual host configuration `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =a1.a.com [OR]` for every subdomain I need, therefore the process is not automated.